# How can I add html tags in string for alignment?

Tags: java, html, text-alignment

I have string data (which is dynamic) which contains following information with format as given below:

```
        UNI_ID          ABCD-211
        Title           Enrolled With 202
        Enrolle         Enrolle IA
        Written         Mr. R D
        Received by     Anny
        Received        18 May 2012 05:32:07

        Billing address:

        Email           abc@abc.com
        Phone number    0049 xxxx 3xxxxxx
        Department      N/A
        Organization    N/A 
        Address line 1  12 c
        Address line 2  VN
        City            London
        State/Province  GB
        Zip/Postcode    xyz
        Country     

                   UK

        Order details: 

        OrderNumber       1232120000
        Order date        18 May 2012
        Purchase order no   
        Currency          GBP
        Product amount      � 9.00
        Admin charge        � 50.00
        VAT amount          � 11.21
        Total amount        � 70.21
```

In above information even Country field is also not well aligned. I need to use  this String in HTML file. But the alignment is not proper?

So I use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` like below:

```java
String details6 =  StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(
        data.replaceAll("\n\n\n", "<br><br>")
            .replaceAll("\n\n\n\n", "<br><br>")
            .replaceAll("\n\n", "<br><br>")
            .replaceAll("\n", "<br>")
            .replaceAll("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
            .replaceAll("\t   ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
            .replace("\r", "")
            .replace("∩┐╜", "&euro;"));
```

Which is giving me output in HTML when render like the below one:

```
            UAN_ID                        ABCD-211
            Title                        Enrolled With 202
            Enrolle                        Enrolle IA
            Written                        Mr. R D
            Received by                Anny
            Received                18 May 2012 05:32:07

            Billing address:

            Email                        abc@abc.com
            Phone number                0049 xxxx 3xxxxxx
            Department                  N\/A
            Organization                N\/A
            Address line 1                12 c
            Address line 2                VN
            City                        London
            State/Province  GB
            State\/Province                MA
            Zip\/Postcode                xyz
            Country                

            UK

            Order details: 

            OrderNumber                1232120000
            Order date                18 May 2012
            Purchase order no        
            Currency                GBP
            Product amount                \uFFFD 9.00
            Admin charge                \uFFFD 50.00
            VAT amount                \uFFFD 11.21
            Total amount                \uFFFD 70.21
```

Is there any way from which I can align the above fields?

Comment: Why you don't use table..?

Comment: @scaisEdge the String object is dynamic which need to be in formatted because it is using as it is in html. like <body> $data</body. so anything in data object is printed as it is.

Comment: then you can't formatting properly .. (or you use only fixed with char) ...